# ffmpeg delogo works not good when delogo at boundary

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I am trying using ffmpeg delogo filter to hide the logo, but I found when the logo is appears at boundary, delogo filter seems works not good. please check following images.

[image]
[image]

I also read a bit of source, seems the algorithm need subtract 1 pixel boundary. in the second image, the delogo result is looks strange, bottom is white. I want to make it invisible, is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i video
  -filter_complex
     "[0]split[m][b];
      [b]crop=iw:144:0:174,vflip[a];
      [m][a]vstack,delogo=794:689:134:40:1,crop=iw:720:0:0"  out.mp4
```

The video is split in two. The 2nd feed is cropped to the bottom 20% but ending at a height just above the logo. This is then flipped and vertically stacked with the main stream. `delogo` is applied making sure that the height of the logo covers the whole logo. Then the excess portion at the bottom is cropped off.

Result:

[image]